# Wrong site name for meta post in user profile in Android app

Tags: bug, profile-page, android-app, meta, site-name

In this user profile, all the "Stack Overflow" questions are actually from the [meta site of Health](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/users/805/carey-gregory).

[image]